# Union All of two tables based on month of a date in Oracle

Tags: oracle, union

I have two tables table_a and table_b as below. column invdate is of date datatype and column amount is of number datatype.

table_a

| invdate | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 20-01-2021 | 50 |
| 20-01-2021 | 100 |
| 20-02-2021 | 50 |
| 20-03-2021 | 50 |

table_b

| invdate | amount |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2021 | 250 |
| 01-02-2021 | 300 |
| 01-03-2021 | 40 |
| 01-03-2021 | 50 |

I am doing a **UNION ALL** of both tables to get the sum of the amounts based on only month and year.

```
SELECT to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY') as "Date", sum(amount) as "Total"
FROM
(
SELECT to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY'), amount
FROM table_a
UNION ALL
SELECT to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY'), amount
FROM table_b
)
GROUP BY to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY')
ORDER BY to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY') asc;
```

to get the final output like below

| Date | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 01-2021 | 400 |
| 02-2021 | 350 |
| 03-2021 | 140 |

but it gives me the below error.

```
ORA-00904: "INVDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 10 Column: 18
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You forget to assign the alias to the output column of the subquery. And to the subquery itself.

```
SELECT "Date", SUM(amount) AS "Total"
FROM ( SELECT to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY') AS "Date", amount
       FROM table_a
       UNION ALL
       SELECT to_char(invdate, 'MM-YYYY'), amount
       FROM table_b
     ) AS unioned_data
GROUP BY "Date"
ORDER BY "Date" asc;
```